# Retry topology if Zookeeper stops working

Tags: apache-storm

Zookeeper of storm is stopped working. Because of this Topologies stop working.Do we any mechanism so that zookeep will start automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You will have do define some supervising over the Zookeeper. try [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [puppet](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/tags/zookeeper)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Zookeeper stopped working"? Did you setup Zookeeper in reliable distributed mode? If yes, Zookeeper should be available all the time and Storm topologies should keep running.

However, if one of you ZK nodes dies, you need to start up a new one manually.

See "Setup up a Zookeeper cluster" in https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

See also https://storm.apache.org/documentation/images/storm-cluster.png from https://storm.apache.org/tutorial.html